# 3D scatter of points with colors as a 4th var

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to scatter a dataset in 3D and for each point using a scalar variable as a color, to visualize better some phenomena.
In order to keep things simple, suppose i want that each point plotted has a color that in some way represents another 3D array (density,temperature, energy,etc..).

How can I do this? I would like something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#some dummy data
x = np.linspace(-1,1,3, endpoint = True )
y  = np.linspace(-1,1,3, endpoint = True )
z = np.linspace(-1,1,3, endpoint = True )
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,indexing = 'ij')
E = X**2+Y**2+Z**2
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, color = VV)
plt.show()
```

here VV would be an array that in some way is proportional to E and that gives to each (x,y,z) a color according to E[x,y,z].
The final part would be to put a  colorbar that helps to read the approximate color value.
I searched already on the forum but the answers I found were not adaptable to 3D datasets and i'm currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem, you can just set `c=E` in your call to `scatter` and Matplotlib will automatically normalise it to fit the colour scale.  `scatter` returns a `PathCollection` which is a type of mappable so can be passed to `colorbar`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#some dummy data
x = np.linspace(-1,1,3, endpoint = True )
y  = np.linspace(-1,1,3, endpoint = True )
z = np.linspace(-1,1,3, endpoint = True )
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z,indexing = 'ij')
E = X**2+Y**2+Z**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
pc = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=E)
fig.colorbar(pc)
plt.show()
```

[image]